# how to scrape content from a line break in a web pages using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, jsdom, cheerio

Good day to you all.

I have 2 question on web-scraping using Cheerio. I went through the questions that might have my answer but could not find one that answer my question so I decided to ask a question.

**Background info:** I only learn Javascript for about 2~3 months so I might ask some really *funny* questions, please pardon me on that.

**Objective:** I'm looking to scrape data from the following site - and

I'm looking to get the

- Name of bike store
- Address of bike store
- Telephone of bike shop

I've managed to scrape that data that I need, however they are lump in a html group (not sure if this is how to call it.
This is the code I used.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = 'http://www.togoparts.com/bikeshops/list_shops.php?country=MY';
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    $ = cheerio.load(body, {
        normalizeWhitespace: false
    });
    var doc = $("td[width='52%'].verdana1");
    doc.each(function() {
        var link = $(this);
        console.log(link.html());

   });
});
```

The result run in a loop and I'm able to get the following. I could not post an image - I have placed the image in the following [link](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s95/sh/cac9c007-f81e-4436-b91c-3748c84b0967/9006b9ec9a6958f693dab675a0f5d22f/deep/0/1.-bosslee@bybosslee----Dropbox-development-web-node-scraping-%28zsh%29.png).

**Question:** How do I get the data separately?

I need the title of the link, I tried `var link = $(this).attr('href');' but does not work.

I also need the info (bikeshop address) after the line break - which I have no idea how to take it.

**Question2:**
I tried the following `var doc = $("td[width='52%'] .verdana1");` - note the space before the .verdana1 - this give me only the title of the bikeshops I wanted, how is this different from `var doc = $("td[width='52%'].verdana1");`

and If I'm using this `var doc = $("td[width='52%'] .verdana1");` - how can I get the data of the bike shop address?

Thank you so much for reading, I been trying to solve this during the Chinese New Year and it is driving me crazy :(. I looking forward to learn from you guys.

Bryan

Comment: Good question. Just one clarification when you say link title you mean the address (url) to which link refers right? for example in something like `<a href='someurl.com'>something here</a>`, you mean the value of href?

Comment: Hello @Pawelmhm 
Thanks for asking :)
I'm actually looking at the title **something here** not the one within _href=_

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of links you can first find them in your document, and then log all href attributes:

```
var doc = $("td[width='52%'].verdana1");
links = doc.find('a');
links.each(function (i,elem) {
    console.log(elem.attribs.href);
})
```

This will log all values of href atttribute.

When it comes to addresses it's more complicated because they are not semantically distinguished in the DOM, they are also children of table cells, so you need nested loops, but you can access them by looking up element that are of type text.

```
doc.each(function (i,elem) {
    # elem here is table cell
    elem.children.forEach(function (child,i) {
       # now all children of table cell (i.e links,spans,divs and just text)
       if (child.type == "text") {
            console.log(child.data);
       }
    })
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Pawelmhm.

Your answer help me a lot, it help me solve at least 80% of my question. I'm almost getting it. I would like to see your advice on how can I remove the <br> within the child.data.

With your help, I'm able to get the address and telephone in different object. But the <br> or the blank space, comes along as object as well.

I'va attached a [gist](https://gist.github.com/bosslee/0068a84161482e0db945) here for your reference

Comment: Hi @Pawelmhm sorry for the repeated msg :D
I managed to solve the reminding 20% 

Thank you so much.